# Как добавить meta-тег при пагинации в MODX Revo

Tags: php, modx

Подскажите, как переписать условие здесь:

```
[[!+page:is=`1`:then=`<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />`:else=`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />`]]
```

Если страница больше 1 то **выводить** мета, в противном случае **не выводить**
ЗЫ: !+page выводит номер страницы в пагинации.
у меня так и не получилось(

Заранее спасибо

Comment: используете `pdoPage` для постраничного вывода? Обновил ответ.

Comment: да использую pdoPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используется [pdoPage](https://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdopage) то можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
[[!#GET.page:is=``:or:if=`[[!#GET.page]]`:is=`1`:then=`Первая`:else=`Не первая`]]
```

Проверяем, непосредственно на наличие `?page`, или `?page=1`

**upd:**
В вашем случаи, стало быть нужно, в секции `<head>..</head>`, где выводятся `мета-теги` `(<title>/<meta name="description".../<meta name="viewport".. итд)`
прописать условие, что выше, с необходимым тегом, а именно `<meta name="robots"..` таким образом:

```
[[!#GET.page:is=``:or:if=`[[!#GET.page]]`:is=`1`:then=`<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />`:else=`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />`]]
```

Также, желаемого результата можно добиться путём добавления в `robots.txt` строки:

```
Disallow: /*?page=
```

В таком случаи, отпадает необходимости мучиться с мета-тегами.

Comment: это две разные функции. Одна через снипет отдельно выводить (первая) другая уже готовое решение

Comment: Работает, но выводит вверху сайта. если я добавляю {+page} вместо {#GET.page} то не работает. что я делаю не так?

Comment: `[[+page]]` не срабатывает, так как он вызывается раньше, чем сам `pdoPage`, на этом этапе в `[[+page]]` ещё нет номера страницы. А чем не подходит `[[!#GET.page..`? он явно берёт из адресной строки параметр `?page`. По поводу *"выводит вверху сайта"* не понял В нужном месте (чанке/шаблоне) эту конструкцию и ставьте.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/g4buwp - вот так выводит, в самом вверху. Я прописываю в хеде там где все мета теги

Comment: @webEugene Ну, тут уже смотря где вы выводите. Да и `Первая/Не первая` я для примера указал, вам же нужно было `мета-тег` выводить. Обновил ответ.

Comment: теперь все работает :) спасибо